# Paging , sorting and filtering in MVC5 5 application which uses ado.net(not entity framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, paging

I am new to paging in MVC application. Our application uses ado.net(not entity framework) for db connectivity. Also the view is not a strongly typed view. So can you suggest efficient way to implement Paging , sorting and filtering?

Comment: Do you require server side paging for download speed, or can user sort and filter in javascript?

Comment: yes need server side paging but if you can share both options that would help in exploring, please share what page control to use  and sample code  with example which I can use to understand.

Answer (score 2):

*simple (and fast) solution*

If you are using **SQL Server 2012 or above** add this piece of code to the end of your query like this

```
query.AppendFormat(" OFFSET {0} ROWS FETCH NEXT {1} ROWS ONLY", criteria.StartIndex, criteria.PageSize);
```

`StartIndex -> (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize`
`PageSize -> "count of items in one page in your view"`

Answer (score 0):

For client side paging I suggest [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

For client side filtering, [tablefilter](https://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/) is really useful.